# How can I use the flow of PagingData from pager3 in a ViewPager2 to side scroll?

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm building a news app, and have successfully built the feed of news articles using pager3 (from [androidx.paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview)). Tapping on a news article then goes to a detailed view of that article (I've used the Navigation component to do that).

The next feature we want to add is the ability to swipe left/right while viewing an article to see the next/previous article in the feed.

As each article details is a `Fragment`, it seemed like the right idea to look at [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2), using its `FragmentStateAdapter`.

However, I can't seem to wire together the flow from pager3 into that adapter?

pager3 supplies an adapter for a `RecyclerView` (this is what I'm using in the main news feed) and ViewPager2 is built on top of a `RecyclerView` but requires a `FragmentStateAdapter`.

It seems like these two libraries are so close together they should just plug into one another, but I'm missing a bit of glue (or I'm missing some fundamental understanding Android development!)

Does anyone have any suggestions how to either make these two libraries work together, or how I should implement my swipe between articles if ViewPager2 was the wrong choice?